# select the closest textarea to a button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, closest

I am having a table `td` which contains a `textarea` and a button and I want to send the value of textarea on button click via AJAX however there is a problem selecting the closest textarea to the button.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".addR", function () {
        paperID = $(this).attr("paperID");
        commentID = $(this).attr("commentID");
        text = $(this).closest("textarea").val();
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                paperID: paperID,
                commentID: commentID,
                text: text
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add_rebuttal.php',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['text']}</td>";
?>
    <td><br /><textarea class="reText" rows='5' name='reText' id='reText' style='width:98%;' type='text'></textarea>
    <button commentID="<?php echo $row['comment_id'] ?>" paperID="<?php echo $paper_id ?>" class="addR" type="button" name="addR" id="addR">send rebuttal</button></td></tr> <?
}
```

The problem is `$(this).closest("textarea").val();` return undefined, so how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

closest() returns the closest **ancestor**. Your textarea is not an ancestor of your button, it's a previous sibling. Instead, try:

```
text = $("textarea", $(this).parent()).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of a textarea you have to use `text()` instead of `val()`. As pointed out by Scotty, the textarea you want is not an ancestor so don't use `closest()`.

Comment: the same problem, which is that the value of the first textarea is taken not the one corresponding to the button